# test values within a subscribe block of a reactive form module's auditTime method

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, karma-jasmine, angular-reactive-forms

I'm attempting to test the values inside of a `.subscribe` block within an angular4/typescript jasmine unit test that uses a `rxjs auditTime` method. I've read a lot of similar posts to this one that don't seem to get me inside that block.

I have the following example component:

**address.component.ts:**

```
export class AddressComponent implements OnInit {

  public form: FormGroup;

  constructor (
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit (): void {
    this.createForm();
  }

  public createForm (): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      lineOne: [this.address.lineOne],
    });

    this.form.valueChanges.auditTime(500).subscribe(() => {
      this.address.lineOne = this.form.value.lineOne;
    });
  }
}
```

**address.component.html:**

```
<div class="address">
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 address-body">
        <div class="form-group-main">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="address-input col-12">
              <label for="address-line-one" [class.required]="isMandatory">Address Line 1</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="address-line-one" type="text" formControlName="lineOne">
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 address-body">
        <display-address [body]="address.lineOne"></display-address>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12">
        <button class="btn btn-full-width btn-primary btn-sm btn-edit" id="address-edit" type="button" (click)="...">Edit</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**address.component.spec.ts:**

```
describe('Address Component', () => {
  let component: AddressComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AddressComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AddressComponent],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    }).compileComponents().then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddressComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

  }));

  it('should update address', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.address = {lineOne: 'street'};
    fixture.detectChanges();

    //do something.. 

  }));

});
```

assuming the above has been setup correctly and i haven't missed something glaringly obvious which is why my tests never provide the correct results, i've tried modifying my test with the following ideas:

spying on auditTime and calling through:

```
spyOn(component.form.valueChanges, 'auditTime').and.callThrough();
```

spying on auditTime and calling fake function:

```
spyOn(component.form.valueChanges,'auditTime').and.callFake(()=> {
    return {
        subscribe: () => {}
    }
});
```

spying on auditTime and returning a value Observable.of:

```
spyOn(component.form.valueChanges,'auditTime').and.returnValue(Observable.of('hello'));
```

calling it directly:

```
component.form.valueChanges.auditTime().subscribe(result => {
   //never get in here
});
```

trying to wait using: `tick()` and trying to flush using: `flushMicrotasks()`.

spying on the createForm function:

```
spyOn(component, 'createForm').and.callFake(() => {
    return Observable.of('hello');
});
```

using debugElement to access and update lineOne always returns errors if i use the following:

```
const el = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector(By.css('#address-line-one'));
el.value = 'something';
el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
fixture.detectChanges();
```

as it would appear it can only see the edit button of the html and `<display-address></display-address>`, suggesting it's maybe not compiled at the time.

I've also tried wrapping everything in:

```
fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    // do something.. 
});
```

and now i'm out of ideas, if anyone can make sense of the above and point me in the right direction, it would be great..

---

### SOLUTION

---

Thanks to Amir, it would appear that in this particular example i had been massively overthinking the answers required for this, and using the `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` was hiding the true problem. It turns out i needed to import the component which `<display-address>` required:

```
imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, DisplayAddressComponent],
```

this allowed the template to compile correctly, meaning that i could see all the form values instead of just `<display-address>`. As recommended i used the combination of `fakeAsync` and `tick(600)` to emit change to the form:

```
it('should update address', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.address = {lineOne: 'street'};
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.address.lineOne).toBe('street');
    component.form.controls['lineOne'].setValue('test');
    tick(600);

    expect(component.address.lineOne).toBe('test');
  }));
```

just if anyone had a similar problem.

Comment: What actually is not working, do you have any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i will just post here my assumptions, check if it helps:

1. **Call ngOnInit()** directly or using **detectChanges()** **right after** you
   **create component**;
2. Test should work **synchronously** only if you use **fakeAsync + tick(600);**
3. **After** you performed **tick(600)** try to emit value into **this.form.valueChanges**, you can do that by **substituting FormBuilder** so it will return object with your own emitter (subject) or by **finding an element in html** and **inputting value with DOM event**.
4. If you decide **to use html for input**, **remove NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA** and see maybe it's not rendered because of **some errors** (because you said that part of html was not present).